# Can I get a phone contacts list with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I have an IOS project that I coordinated with the project manager to do PWA and web application now I need to have access to the phone's contact list!
Is it possible for me to get the audience list with JavaScript?
If possible, please give me a sample code!
I'm really a noob in JavaScript and nuxt and I need your friends' help!
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can PWA access contacts, gps or use the phone camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693406/can-pwa-access-contacts-gps-or-use-the-phone-camera)

Comment: You can with the [Contacts API](https://wicg.github.io/contact-api/spec/) But it only works in Chrome for Android 80+ and is experimental. [Example](https://github.com/pierresaid/web-contact)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't access phone contacts with PWA, native app is the only way to do that.

List of avaliable features is can be found here [here](https://whatwebcando.today/), for contacts, check the "Operating System" section

Comment: Can we put a function in that list by tapping it and selecting one and the data of that audience coming back to me?

Comment: If i understood you correctly, you would want the user to open their contacts, select one value and you should have it available in the app? If thats what you're asking the answer is still no